# How are the 16 General Purpose Registers represented in Intel PIN binary instrumentation tool

Tags: x86-64, intel, instrumentation, intel-pin

I know how the 1st 8 general purpose registers are represented in PIN, like REG_GAX, REG_GBX and so on. However I cant seem to find in the user manual how registers r8  to r15 are represented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`REG_GAX` and `REG_GBX` are shorthand registers, for example `REG_GAX` is `REG_RAX` in 64-bit or `REG_EAX` in 32-bit.

Excerpt from `source/include/pin/gen/reg_ia32.PH`, see also the [file on github](https://github.com/sarachour/siact/blob/master/tool/pin-2.12-58423-gcc.4.4.7-linux/source/include/pin/gen/reg_ia32.PH#L60):

> REG_GAX = REG_RAX,      ///< eax on a 32 bit machine, rax on 64

As R8 up to R15 don't exist on 32-bit architecture, they have no shorthand except their own name (`REG_R8`, `REG_R9`, ...)